# Custom TableView iOS - General questions

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is more of a general question. I want to create a scene where the top 1/3 of the scene is say a slider with some text labels, and then the rest 2/3rds of the scene is a data table of recorded values of the above slider(user moves the slider to the correct value, hits 'enter', and the recorded value is showed in the data table below). I assume this is a modified table view, but I'm not sure? Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to go about doing this? Im not quite sure where to begin looking up information/tutorials on this type of layout. Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks so much!

Comment: Just do it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create a UIViewController that contains the UISlider and a UITableView within it's xib file. Hook the view elements to its ViewController.h, and set your ViewController as a UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.

In ViewController.m, fetch the data follow the UITableView protocols to load it into cells. Then, when you would like to refresh data call 
[myTableView reloadData];

[Apple's UITableViewDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

[Apple's UITableViewDataSource Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info...Ill try and mess around with why you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a "modified table view". It's a table view. There's no problem here; you have a scene with a UISlider, some UILabels, and a UITableView. There is nothing to "look up". No law says that a UITableView has to occupy the entire scene interface - though of course in that case you can't use a UITableViewController, but that's no restriction at all. Just set your table view's delegate and data source to the view controller that owns the scene.